# Storing facebook data to mysql

Tags: mysql, facebook, user-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to save more than 2 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651241/unable-to-save-more-than-2-records)

I am using Facebook Javascript SDK to login and get user info. When I save this data to mysql database it save only 1-2 records only. While I am getting user record every time.

```
if($user){
                print_r($userInfo);
                $userid = $userInfo[id];
                $username = $userInfo[name];
                $birthday = $userInfo[birthday];
                $birthday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($birthday));
                $userlocation = $userInfo[location][name];
                $gender = $userInfo[gender];
                $useremail = $userInfo[email];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (userid, username, useremail, birthday, location, gender) VALUES ('$userid', '$username', '$useremail', '$birthday', '$userlocation', '$gender')";
                if($result = mysql_query($sql)) {
                    echo "success";
                }
            }
```

table def for users is :

```
1   userid  int(20)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     Primary      Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
 2  username    varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial      Fulltext
 3  useremail   varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial      Fulltext
 4  birthday    date            No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
 5  location    varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial      Fulltext
 6  gender  varchar(10) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial      Fulltext
```

when using PDO :

```
if($user){
                $host = "internal-db.s130813.gridserver.com";
                $db = "db130813_fbmooz";
                $user = "db130813_adminu";
                $pass = "ansari786";
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
                $uid = $userInfo[id];
                $uname = $userInfo[name];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (userid,username) VALUES (:uid,:uname)";
                $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array(':uid'=>$uid, ':uname'=>$uname));
```

Still could not be saved

Comment: How many records would you expect to get?

Comment: depends upon users it may be upto several hundreds

Comment: So this bit of code is being called repeatedly? I guess Im missing where it should be inserting so many records.

Comment: this code will get executed every time a new user login through FB id, I will place a check of fb id in database later on , but at present I am expecting atleast 20-25 records.

Comment: Are you seeing as many values / hits at the 'print_r' line as you would expect but the INSERT isn't being called? Or this bit of code isn't getting called? I guess I don't know if this is a larger code issue or a mysql issue.

Comment: yes, all the values every time printed on screen using print_r but INSERTED is not initiated after 2 records

Comment: What's the table def for 'users'? Any chance there is a PK or index getting in the way?

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts come to mind:

- rewrite this using PDO - the 'mysql_query' fn is deprecated
- use a prepared statement and 'mysql_real_escape_string' to make sure the values don't have any bad chars
- check the return value and use 'mysql_error()' to see if something went wrong